# Do Monaca Build Windows Apps Work on WIndows 10?

Tags: build, windows, monaca

I built an app in Monaca, and have successfully deployed and published it on google play and the App Store. I know I have to sign it with visual studio to publish it in the windows store, but can manually install it using powershell for development purposes. However, even though it works on android and ios, it crashes immediately after launching in Windows 10. I read over the documentation, and my question is: Is it even compatible? Everything in the documentation is either outdated or stictly for windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are compatible. I finally installed and ran it successfully.